# docker login fails: tls: server selected unsupported protocol version 301

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry, docker-image

I am using **`docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`** in a Windows machine and I am trying to login to Artifactory using the following command,

```
docker login docker-registery.company.net
```

It prompts for username and password and I am providing them, however I am not able to login. It gives me the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registery.company.net/v2/: tls: server selected unsupported protocol version 301
```

Note: I am able to login to the Artifactory Repo Browser through my web browser by using the same username and password.

What is causing this issue when I try to login from the command-line? Is it some kind of proxy or certificate issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`protocol version 301` = TLS 1.0 - that is insecure TLS version, which has been selected by the server (in theory by Artifactory, but there can be reverse proxy, Tomcat, etc. where TLS can be configured as well).

Configure properly TLS on the server side (enable support for TLS 1.1+) and your docker client will be able to establish a secure TLS connection. "insecure registry" is just insecure workaround.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer, it is just a work around. I do not have access to the Artifactory server configurations so this works for me now. However, I will ask the administrator to configure proper TLS.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue after some of [Windows update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi)

You can manually change the default TLS version in windows by editing register

Change needed values in regedit.exe or store this code as .reg file and execute it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]

"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001



[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]

"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
```

Hope, it will solve your problem

Comment: What value worked for you? Are you using Artiactory too?

Comment: As in example - value '1'. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-office-online-server). No, i am not using Artifactory .  But to define that problem is with tls (default tls version) try open Artifactory in Google Chrome and in Internet Explorer. Is it working in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`docker login --username=yourUserName --email=abc@company.net dockerregistry.company.net:5000`

Obviously, if you are using a port other than 5000 specify it after the colon.

Once you log in, you can do something like

```
docker push dockerregistry.company.net:5000/ubuntu
```

or

```
docker pull dockerregistry.company.net:5000/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers actually worked for me.

However, I manged to find a fix for it. Keep in mind that, this is not a perfect solution but a work around.

Here it goes...

I added my Artifactory registry as an insecure registry. Here's how to do it: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Therefore, by passing the TLS handshake.